# Spark Mail by Readle not adding accepted calendar invites to my calendar

Tags: google-calendar, email

Anytime I get a calendar invite in spark mail when I accept it will not add it to my Google calendar. It even sends an RSVP to the person that sent me the invite but it won't add it to my calendar. This happens on the Android version (Pixel 3), the iPad version, and even the Mac version. I've tried reinstalling several times. I've even tried deleting my spark account and starting over with no luck. I've tried reaching out to spark support with no luck.

I'm stuck here. I really love spark, but this calendar thing is driving me nuts and I don't know what to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is happening to me as well. Haven’t been able to figure it out.

Comment: This is the same for me and makes this cool tool close to unusable :-(

My current workaround is to click on the 'Open related message' under the email and to open the Meeting.ics file

But it does not work if invitation gets updated

Anybody from Spark here ?

Comment: Same problem here. Anybody found a solution?

Comment: I contacted spark customer service about it at the time and never heard back after sending the diagnostic stuff they asked for.

Comment: Happening to me too.

Comment: What calendars are you using? Mine is icloud.

Comment: google calendar.

Comment: any update on this? the only thing i found is to remove calendar and add it again, both to the internet accounts in settings, and in the spark app

Comment: nope all crickets on my end.

Comment: Same happens to me. Switched today to Microsoft Outlook because of that

Comment: Same here, such a shame!